# Prediction from gam model at X = 0 not equal to intercept

Tags: nonparametric, prediction, splines, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I'm having a problem with GAM.  Specifically when I try to make a prediction at a new data value at the origin, my prediction is not equal to the intercept.  Can someone help me understand why this is happening?  Here is an example:

```
set.seed(42)
N = 1000
x = runif(N)
y = x^.22+rnorm(N)
m = gam(y~s(x))
summary(m)
predict(m,newdata = data.frame(x=0))

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
y ~ s(x)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.78115    0.03164   24.69   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
       edf Ref.df     F  p-value    
s(x) 2.158  2.687 13.79 7.61e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.0344   Deviance explained = 3.65%
GCV score = 1.0043  Scale est. = 1.0011    n = 1000
1> predict(m,newdata = data.frame(x=0))
        1 
0.3756038
```

I think the prediction should be equal to the intercept when x = 0, but it's not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You think wrong since your are not considering the spline functions! Let's first evaluate the spline at your new data i.e. 0. To do that I will use the predict function but with the type argument as `terms`.

```
> spline.at.0=predict(m,newdata = data.frame(x=0), type = "terms")
> spline.at.0
        s(x)
1 -0.4055495
attr(,"constant")
(Intercept) 
  0.7811533
```

Now lets look at the coefficients of your fitted model `m`

```
> coef(m)
  (Intercept)        s(x).1        s(x).2        s(x).3        s(x).4        s(x).5        s(x).6        s(x).7 
 7.811533e-01 -5.353668e-02  1.676821e-02 -3.391826e-05 -1.724044e-02 -4.702938e-03 -1.383030e-02 -3.876392e-03 
       s(x).8        s(x).9 
 1.009809e-01  2.413780e-01
```

So the first one is actually the intercept. When you use the predict function (without specifying exactly the type argument), it gives you by default  the linear predictor i.e. :

```
> predict.at.0=coef(m)[1]+spline.at.0
> predict.at.0
       s(x)
1 0.3756038
attr(,"constant")
(Intercept) 
  0.7811533
```

Which is basically the same as:

```
> predict(m,newdata = data.frame(x=0))
        1 
0.3756038
```

I recommend you to see the help file `?predict.gam` in package `mgcv`. BTW, you need to add the package you are using ... like `require(mgcv)` in your code since there are more than one package doing GAM.

Comment: thank you!  does this have something to do with the "identifiability constraints"?  I never understand what is meant by that.